# Open php page in Fancybox, lightbox etc on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, image, fancybox, lightbox

I have a user profile page and want to allow the user to do the following:

1. Click 'CHANGE AVATAR'
2. Select new pic and upload it
3. Pic shows in lightbox (of some sort)
4. Allow the user to use `jcrop` to crop image
5. Save cropped image in user folder

I can achieve the upload part and know how to use php to save a file to user folder and add filename to the users row in mysql table for avatar.

I can find no tutorials to show me how to open the image in a lightbox ad enable the user to edit with jcrop.

I figure I will have to:

1. post the uploaded filename to a php file (ajax?)
2. include the php file in an iframe to use with fancybox (or alternative)
3. echo the uploaded image and initialize jcrop within the php file for the shown image
4. Save the image with random filename using php

I am stuck with points 2-4 on the last list. Please help...

**Can nobody seriously help me with this??**

Comment: Well I have done it before but, it's hard to explain complete steps here. I would suggest to try PLupload library and bPopup. it make work easy for sure.

Comment: I'm fine with the upload part, its opening the image in a lightbox and using jcrop I don't get